# Are there any mountaineering/hiking activities in or near Albufeira, Portugal?

Tags: portugal

I'm heading over to Albufeira, Portugal on Thursday and I was just wondering if there are any **hiking** or **mountaineering** activities, or **outdoor landmarks** worth seeing in the area (or close by).

I don't want to be stuck on the beach with my friends the whole holiday, and from what I can see on [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attractions-g189112-Activities-Albufeira_Faro_District_Algarve.html) it's just beaches/typical tourist stuff.

Anyone know of any, through resources/personal experiences local to there?

**Note**:

- I would define local as probably within 25 miles of Albufeira.
- I haven't been to Portugal previously, so I'm unaware of any of the surrounding areas. (I'll be going off Google Maps or a real map of some kind only)

Comment: See also [Outdoors.SE].

Comment: @gerrit cheers, didn't know that existed.

Comment: If you turn on the terrain option in Google Maps you find the Serra de Monchique a little bit to the northwest. Google suggests there is some hiking there (admittedly, it is further (closer to 35 miles), but it still might be worthwile to dig into options there). (I haven't been there either, all my info comes from Google.)

Comment: @martin.koeberl thanks for the head-ups! I'll be sure to check it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [bicycle trail](http://portugalbiketours.com/en/llr/news/cycling-algarve) runs the entire length of the Algarve. (I am not affiliated with any business at that link.) Part traverses the [Parque Natural da Ria Formosa](http://www.algarvewildlife.com/reserves-formosa.php), and is also a pedestrian path. It's completely flat, so if intense mountaineering is the goal, not a good recommendation. But if you are interested in either flowers or birds, it might be an informative and enjoyable outing.

The southwest tip of Europe at Sagres is also worth getting to. Same trail.

The typical tourist stuff includes enormous and inexpensive-for-Europe fish dinners.

Comment: Brilliant recommendation, I'm looking for anything but the beach! I'll certainly be taking this.